# DataTable convert row datetime to string

Tags: c#

First I apologize for my bad english :) I am taking the data in the database I have a column "SonGirisTarihi" it is a Datetime

i want to in my datagridview if the date is empty write a string like "bla bla" but the error is because the row is datetime how can i convert row. i hope i can tell

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataTable dt = db.GetDataSet("musteri").Tables["musteri"];

foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows) {
    if (Row["SonGirisTarihi"] == DBNull.Value) //SonGirisTarihi is datetime
    {
          Row["SonGirisTarihi"] = "blabla"; 
    }
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
db.disconnect();
```

Comment: Dont loop thru the DGV rows.  Since your DGV has a datasource use something like the CellFormatting event - that is what it is for.  You will also likely have to respond to the Parsing event to convert "bla bla" back to null/empty

Comment: Post the code for your `DataGridView`. You should do it there directly on the grid column, not like your doing it on the row.

Comment: Racil Hilan Plutonix thx dude

Comment: Since the DGV knows how to display dates perfectly well, you might be able to use the DefaultCellStyle to display "bla bla" using the NullValue property....dudette

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample using Plutonix's suggestion of using the `NullValue` property.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewDateTime_47208900
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        BindingList<dgvEntry> dgvDataSource = new BindingList<dgvEntry>();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitDGV();
            AddData();
        }

        private void AddData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvEntry entry = new dgvEntry();
                entry.name = $"name {i}";
                entry.id = i;
                //add DateTime to only some of the entries to get some null values
                if (i % 2 > 0)
                {
                    entry.dateTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
                dgvDataSource.Add(entry);
            }
        }

        private void InitDGV()
        {
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            DataGridViewColumn dgvc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dgvc.DataPropertyName = "name";
            DataGridViewColumn dgvc2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dgvc2.DataPropertyName = "id";
            DataGridViewColumn dgvc3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dgvc3.DataPropertyName = "dateTime";
            dgvc3.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "bla bla bla"; //What to do when the value is null
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvc);
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvc2);
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvc3);
            dgv.DataSource = dgvDataSource;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
        }
    }

    public class dgvEntry
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```